# disable z buffering is not working using directxtk

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to disable and enable z buffer, but still the skydome writes to the zbuffer. I'm using the DirectXTK for that purpose, but it seems its not working probably.

```
    CommonStates states(m_Graphics.getDevice());
    m_Graphics.getContext()->RSSetState(states.CullNone());
    XMMATRIX sphereWorld;
    XMMATRIX sphereScale = XMMatrixScaling(200.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    XMMATRIX Translation = XMMatrixTranslation(m_Camera.Position().x, 
        m_Camera.Position().y, m_Camera.Position().z);

    sphereWorld = sphereScale*Translation;
    m_Graphics.getContext()->OMSetDepthStencilState(states.DepthNone(), 1);
    m_shape->Draw(sphereWorld,m_Camera.ViewMatrix(), m_Camera.ProjectionMatrix(), Colors::White, m_texture.Get());
    m_Graphics.getContext()->OMSetDepthStencilState(states.DepthDefault(),1);

    XMMATRIX cameraInverse = XMMatrixInverse(nullptr, m_Graphics.getViewMatrix());
    XMMATRIX translate = XMMatrixTranslation( 2.0f, -3.0f, 2.0f);
    XMMATRIX rotation = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw((float)XM_PI/9.0f, (float)XM_PI/0.2f, (float)XM_PI/0.1f);
    XMMATRIX world = rotation *translate *cameraInverse;

    m_Tiny->Draw(m_Graphics.getContext(), states, world, m_Graphics.getViewMatrix(), m_Graphics.getProjectionMatrix());

    m_Graphics.getContext()->RSSetState(states.CullCounterClockwise());
    m_Graphics.getContext()->RSSetState(states.Wireframe());

    m_Grid.DrawGrid();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GeometricPrimitive` and `Model` both set the required render state internally including the depth/stencil state as part of their API.

For [GeometricPrimitive](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/GeometricPrimitive#simple-drawing), you make use of the `setCustomState` callback to override the default state settings. For example, here's an example using a lambda :

```
m_shape->Draw(sphereWorld,m_Camera.ViewMatrix(), m_Camera.ProjectionMatrix(),
Colors::White, m_texture.Get(), false, [=]
{
    m_Graphics.getContext()->RSSetState(states.CullNone());
    m_Graphics.getContext()->OMSetDepthStencilState(states.DepthNone(), 1);
});
```

For [Model](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Model), you can use the same `setCustomState` callback on the `Draw` method for a quick tweak, or you can just implement the Advanced Drawing pattern. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ModelMesh#advanced-drawing)